# string.Replace in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With c# there is a string.Replace-method.
Like This:

```
string oldString = "stackoverflow";   

string newString= oldString.Replace("stackover","");
```

Output: `flow`

Can I do something similar to this with AngularJs?

My try doesn't work:

```
var oldString = "stackoverflow";

$scope.newString= oldString.Replace("stackover","NO");
```

Comment: in javascript it is `replace` not `Replace` see your console for clues...

Comment: I rolled this back instead of deleting it - in this state the question and the answers all make sense, I'd rather do that than delete it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Javascript method names are camel case, so it's `replace`, not `Replace`:

```
$scope.newString = oldString.replace("stackover","NO");
```

Note that contrary to how the .NET `Replace` method works, the Javascript `replace` method replaces only the first occurrence if you are using a string as first parameter. If you want to replace all occurrences you need to use a regular expression so that you can specify the global (g) flag:

```
$scope.newString = oldString.replace(/stackover/g,"NO");
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f0ot146x/) example.

Comment: thanks for the answer. If I'm using a regular string it works. But I think something else is wrong, because my `oldString` is in Json and looks like this: `[{"id":"RavenUsers/172"},{"id":"RavenUsers/173"},{"id":"RavenUsers/174"}]` . Why doesn't it work on that?

Comment: I've seen the fiddle that it works. But I'm then trying to write it out in the html like this `{{newString }}` But it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3228992: When you edit your question, please don't remove all traces of the original question, it makes the answers look like they are answering some different queston (which they actually are...). What you have isn't a string, it's an array of objects. The response is deserialised from JSON by the `$http.get` method. You would need to loop through the items in the array and do the replace on the property in each object.

Comment: How to replace a comma with a new line?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is:

```
var oldstr="Angular isn't easy";
var newstr=oldstr.toString().replace("isn't","is");
```

Comment: How to replace a comma with a new line?

Answer (score 1):

```
var oldString = "stackoverflow";
var str=oldString.replace(/stackover/g,"NO");
$scope.newString= str;
```

It works for me.
Use an intermediate variable.